# Dynamic column aggregation SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

This is actually the first question that I've ever asked, but I've been helped immensely by the answers to many others, so thanks a ton for that and apologies for the length of this question - I've googled around, but struggled to find anything applicable.

The place I work has a lot of reports that are basically variations on a theme, in most cases the procedures are all very similar.

Most of the variation is really just aggregating the same numeric fields by different categorical ones (the IDs for the categorical fields all being indexed)

This at the moment is handled by having different stored procedures for each variation, while this works it's turning into a little bit of a nightmare from a maintenance perspective.

I'm pretty new to SQL, but the idea hit me that I could take something like this (simplified example, variables are parameters to the proc):

```
--First procedure
declare @pAnID int = 5

select g.AnID
,sum(g.ANumeric) as 'ANumeric'
from dbo.ATable g (nolock)

where g.AnID = 5

group by g.AnID


--Second procedure
declare @pAnotherID int = 5

select g.AnotherID
,sum(g.ANumeric) as 'ANumeric'
from dbo.ATable g (nolock)

where g.AnotherID = 5

group by g.AnotherID
```

And turn it into something like this (variables would be parameters into the procedure):

```
--New procedure
declare @pAnotherID int = 5
declare @pAnID int = null


select case
    when @pAnID = null then g.AnotherID
    else g.AnID
end as 'CorrectID'
,sum(g.ANumeric) as 'ANumeric'
from dbo.ATable g (nolock)

where
(
    @pAnID = null
    or g.AnID = @pAnID
)
and
(
    @pAnotherID = null
    or g.AnotherID = @pAnotherID
)

group by case
    when @pAnID = null then g.AnotherID
    else g.AnID
end
```

Now, when I test it (not using made up names and so on) this does seem to work, however - there is a catch. Looking at the execution plans, SQL Server appears to no longer use the existing indexes on those fields, so maintainable but the performance suffers by a factor of 5-6 which is less than ideal.

I've checked to make sure that I'm not going over any tipping points or anything, index statistics are up to date, fragmentation < 1% so I'm starting to run out of ideas.

I was hoping that as it's a procedure, SQL Server could sniff the parameter infer that it would always be running a comparison & sort/hash on a single column and that therefore that it'd be a good idea to use the index for that column...but unfortunately that doesn't seem to be the case.

I could re-write the thing to use dynamic SQL and dynamically apply table hints...but that then hammers CPU with recompiles and detracts considerably from the idea of actually improving the maintainability of the code.

I don't suppose that anyone else has been in this position or a similar one and found a way to get SQL Server to use indexes with case'd group bys?

Comment: Instead of CASE etc, why not build the report query dynamically and execute that? Then you can make specific optimized queries instead of a single query that fits all.

Comment: Hi @AllanS.Hansen - I certainly could refactor the whole thing to use dymamic sql, but this'd result in a lot of plan cache pollution and some pretty nasty CPU overhead for constant recompilation. While the question of whether this is the lesser of two evils is a good one, I'd ideally like to avoid that if there is a way.

Comment: Your "one-size-fits-all" query is likely to have many more of those issues on top of the complexity of maintenance when you need to change/add to it..

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen - it's not so much as a one-size-fits-all as a one-size-fits-five there would be 12 of these new procs to replace 60 existing procs. The main changes are to the business logic, as opposed to adding new fields to aggregate by (these are fixed). Changes are more like when we decide that RatioX should be MetricA/MetricC rather than MetricA/MetricB. At the moment, that same change needs to be applied in 5 places.